# Java Reflection/Generic

Tags: java, generics, reflection, selenium-webdriver

Given the following three classes how can I use reflection to call the initialize function for the parent class(es) and then the subclass:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtendedElement ee = new ExtendedElement();
        initialize(ee);
     }

    public static void initialize(Element element) {
        System.out.println(element.getClass());
        initialize(element.getClass());
    }

    public static void initialize(Class clazz) {
        System.out.println(clazz.getClass());
    }
}

public class Element {
    protected String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}

public class ExtendedElement extends Element {
    protected String extendedValue;
    public void setExtendedValue(String extendedValue) {
        this.extendedValue = extendedValue;
    }
    public String getExtendedValue() { return extendedValue; }
}
```

I'm not quite sure on how to paramertize the initialize function in the Test class, as the clazz parameter is a raw type.

What I essentially need is to call initialize up the class hierarchy if what I pass into initialize is of a subclass of Element.

Something like the following:

```
public void initialize(Class clazz) { 
    if (Element.class.isInstance(clazz.getClass().getSuperclass()) {
         initialize(clazz.getClass().getSuperclass());
    }
    //Work to call initialize function 
}
```

Edit 1:

Can't I parameterize the above pseudo function differently to retain the type of the object and then call the function I need to?

What I'm trying to do is avoid having to have the same method overridden for each of my classes and allow some inheritance for my Selenium 2 Page Objects.  What I need to do is be able to is introspect the superclass(es) of my self and initialize each of my WebElement fields prior to running tests on these fields.

These are being injected with spring, and to further complicate things I am allowing tests to be written using Spring Expression language.  I am lazy loading my beans, and using the InitializingBean interface to attempt to initialize my WebElements prior to their usage to avoid NPEs.

I had to wrap the WebElements with a custom object so that I could inject the location strategies using spring (We reuse a lot of pieces, but they have different ids / class names dependent upon where they are used in the application; this was done prior to me getting here and will not be changed at this time despite my arguments for consistency).  For example we have a date widget that has different granularities, sometimes we need just a month, sometimes month and year, etc...  It'd be nice if I could use an abstract class and break these commonalities down to their least common denominator and extend from there.  To do that I need to be able to do the following in my base class:

```
public abstract class PageObject implements InitializingBean {
    ...
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        //Pass in concrete impl we are working with - this allows me to initialize properly
        initializeWebElements(this.getClass());
    }
    ...
    public void initializeWebElements(Class clazz) {
        //This does not grab inherited fields, which also need to be initialized
        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (WidgetElement.class == field.getType()) {
                Method getWidgetElement = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("get" +
                    StringUtils.capitalize(field.getName()), new Class [] {});
                    WidgetElement element = 
                      (WidgetElement) getWidgetElement.invoke(this, new Object [] {});
                    element.initElement();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my temporary solution, leaving question open to hopefully gather some better answers though for my use case.

```
public abstract class PageObject implements InitializingBean {
...
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    Class clazz = this.getClass();
    do {
        initializeElements(clazz);
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    } while (clazz != null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a method at a specific level. The only thing is you have access to the `super` keyword inside the class itself.

To make this work, you want to call `super.initialize()` from within each subclass, then just call it via reflection.

This is not C++, where you *can* call a specific method at a specific level of the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that I call super.initialize until a NoSuchMethodException is thrown though?  That doesn't smell right.

Comment: I think you are wrong about this.  @Scott is trying to call `static` methods, and the restrictions on calling overridden methods do not apply to static methods.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not quite sure on how to parameterize the initialize function in the Test class, as the clazz parameter is a raw type.

Nothing in your example requires you to make use of the generic type parameter, so declare it as `Class<?>`.

I don't understand what your initialize methods are really trying to do, but there are a number of problems:

You seem to have one `initialize` method that takes an instance (of `Element`) as an argument, and another that takes a `Class` object as an argument.  That's really apples and oranges stuff ... and you need to explain what you are trying to do.

Your attempt at fleshing out the method contains this:

```
Element.class.isInstance(clazz.getClass().getSuperclass())
```

This will never evaluate to true, because it is asking if some `Class` object is an *instance* of the `Element` class.  (What is more, `clazz.getClass().getSuperclass()` is actually going to be the same as `java.lang.Object.class`.  The class of a `Class` object is `java.lang.Class` and its superclass is `java.lang.Object`).

But I can't figure out what it should be, because you don't clearly describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @aioobe - you win.  I've undeleted it :-)